# jQuery hover, mouseenter, mouseleave state (opacity animate)

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave, jquery-hover

I am trying to understand them but seems like I cannot. So I thought if someone can help me to better understand how these works.

When I add hover state it simply do opacity effect whether mouse is on the element or when mouse leaves element... It repeats it...

And mouseenter&leave works fine but I don't know how to tell him once $(this) so I made something and it works but perhaps someone may tell me what is correct and better way.

```
$("nav.topMenu-left li, nav.topMenu-right li").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '0.5'}, 100);
});

$("nav.topMenu-left li, nav.topMenu-right li").on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your event handlers:

```
$("nav.topMenu-left li, nav.topMenu-right li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
   if (e.type === 'mouseenter')
      $(this).animate({'opacity': '0.5'}, 100);
   else 
      $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 100);   
});
```

Or as you are not delegating the events you can use `hover` method:

```
$("nav.topMenu-left li, nav.topMenu-right li").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '0.5'}, 100);
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 100);   
})
```

Comment: They both works fine... Thanks for both of them!
I will play arround with different things. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option, I would do this with CSS.

Example code using CSS's [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover) property

**CSS**

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;                
    opacity: .5;
}
div:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xUHm/)**

Otherwise, @undefined's solution is what you're looking for =)

Comment: Yeh I just didn't wanted to use transition for easeing. Thanks tho +1 :)

Comment: Ah, well in that case @undefined has it right. The `hover` method in jquery can accept 2 functions (the first is mouseenter, the second is mouseleave) `.hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )`. http://api.jquery.com/hover/