# how to stop rapid hover events in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I want to add buttons to my carousel that show up when the user is hovered over the carousel and hide them when they leave that element.

I've done that, but when I rapidly enter and leave the element being hovered, the animation (opacity 0-1) happens repeatedly once I stop.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate. You have to quickly enter and leave the result box to see what I mean (the black flashly things are a representation of my buttons)

http://jsfiddle.net/BrshS/

```
transitions the opacity on hover, but repeats it a lot when hovered many times
```

anybody know how i can stop this from happening? much appreciated, been at it for hours (i.e. almost the whole day :/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727561/jquery-hover-mouseenter-mouseleave-state-opacity-animate?rq=1 seems to have answered it. why do i need to add 100 to animate() as a second parameter?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but it's the time in milliseconds for the animation to complete. Default is 300 milliseconds I believe.

Comment: @a7omiton that doesn't stop it, it just makes it less obvious. if you hover 10 times in 100 ms, it's going to take 1 second for it to finish fading in and out.

Comment: @KevinB yeah ahren showed me that fault, i understand that now. thanks for making it clear, i'm going with the css3 alternative thank God

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BrshS/3/) to use CSS3 animations as that's the way to go nowadays. No javascript needed, better performance and graceful degradation for free!

```
.next,
.prev {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.image_carousel:hover .next,
.image_carousel:hover .prev {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: omg i wanted to do it in css first but never thought about opacity in css, was so frustrated with jquery. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.fadeTo()` instead of the animation method, as well as `.stop()` to interrupt the current animation.

```
  var $buttons = $('#next, #prev').hide();

  $('.image_carousel').hover(function() {
    $buttons.stop().fadeTo(300,1);
  },
  function(){
    $buttons.stop().fadeTo(300,0);
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BrshS/2/

Comment: this method actually stops the animation which is what I wanted to do initially, thank you very much, can't believe i overlooked stop() :P

Answer (score 0):

you can *"stop"* it with the `stop` method,

```
x.stop(true,true).animate(
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/BrshS/4/

or maybe even the `finish` method.

```
x.finish().animate(
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/BrshS/5/